# PCA magnitude of principal components?

Tags: pca, interpretation

I would like to ask how one should interpret the magnitude of principal components.
I have two sets of measurement (e.g. height and weight) on a group of individuals treated with a compound (e.g. either a placebo control or 4 different drugs). For each measurement I have 3 replicates. I have now performed PCA both on the height and on the weight and I got something like this.

[image]

What I see is that for both the height and weight the drug GREEN has no effect, as the green dots are closed to the black ones (placebo control). Drugs BLUE and GREY are very similar as they have similar effect, and are cluster far from the placebo. Drug RED has also an effect on height and weight, but it is lower compared to the BLUE and GRAY.

Now if I look at the magnitude of PC1 and PC2 in the two plots, they are quite different, the range of the x and y axis for the weight is bigger. Does this tells me something? can I say that the effect of the drugs GREY and BLUE is higher on the weight than on the height?

If the magnitude is not relevant, is it OK to plot the two PCA on the  same 'Cartesian space' ? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: are the height and weight on different non-overlapping datasets? If not, why not put all your variables into one set for PCA (scaling them appropriately before calculation).

Comment: indeed the variables are non-overlapping, so I cannot combined the data in a single matrix.